# How many Star Trek societies have cloaking technology?

Tags: star-trek

The Romulans developed it, and the Klingons stole, it but are there any others who possess it either through theft or development?

Comment: The Dominion had cloaking tech if I remember correctly. So did starfleet at somepoint.

Comment: The Dominion’s genetically-engineered soldier race, the Jem’Hadar, had *individual* cloaking tech, Predator-style. *GET TO DAH CHOPPAH*

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I don't think it is tech, because the Jem'Hadar child that is found and raised by Odo is able to cloak without having access to any of the Dominion tech.

Comment: @JackBNimble: excellent point. Although they are genetically-engineered (I think the Founders might literally have created them), so maybe it’s kind of tech? (Have I/we had this discussion before?)

Comment: Paul, yes when it was how small a cloak can be. Personal cloaking devices.

Comment: [Of course](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55226/what-is-the-smallest-cloaking-device-in-the-star-trek-universe). Oh lord, I even typed “Predator-style” there too. Sorry for Groundhog Day-ing all over your question!

Comment: It sounds like nearly everyone *has* cloaking technology. A better question might be who *uses* cloaking tech regularly.

Comment: @JoeL. The Federation is forbidden from developing it.  Whenever Starfleet made use of it, it was either illegal (the Pegasus), or on loan (the Defiant during the Dominion war).  Morgan, do you count edge cases like this as "have cloaking technology"?  And are you asking at a specific point in the timeline, or at any point?

Comment: The Klingons stole cloaking technology? I'm pretty sure they traded for the technology with the Romulans. Klingons had well-designed ships but no cloaks. Romulans had poorly designed ships that could cloak. They traded information and everybody won. This is why a lot of Klingon and Romulan ships have many similarities with avian-like designs, and even in naming.

Comment: See [Klingon History on Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Klingon_history#Klingon-Federation_Cold_War). If you scroll down a ways, there's this note: "Production sources indicate that the Romulans and Klingons entered in a brief alliance (see Klingon-Romulan relations), including a technological exchange, in which the Klingons received cloaking technology in trade for D7-class battle cruisers. Possibly, the Battle of Klach D'Kel Brakt marked the preliminary end of this cooperation."

Comment: @Izkata I was curious who has that tech. Who actually uses it can be evaluated on a case by case basis.

Comment: In the TNG epsiode Hero Worship it was said the Breen had cloaking devices, but they were never showed using them in DS9.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to the cultures mentioned, [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cloaking_device) mentions several others:

- The Federation (seen on the *USS Defiant*, Self-replicating mines and the Federation Holoship in *Insurrection*)
- The Terran Empire (seen on the *ISS Enterprise*)
- The Cardassian Obsidian Order (seen on the *Koranak*)
- The Kraylor (seen on the *Nightingale*)
- The Klingon-Cardassian Alliance (seen on the Regent's flagship
- The Remans (seen on the *Scimitar*)
- The Voth (seen on the Voth City Ship and the Voth research vessel)
- The Krenim Imperium (seen on the Krenim weapon ship)
- The Aldeans (seen on Aldea)
- The Sphere Builders (seen on the Delphic Expanse spheres)
- The Minosians (seen on Echo Papa 607)
- The Srivani (seen on Srivani vessels)
- The Hierarchy (seen on their ships)
- The Xyrillians (seen on their starships)

Bear in mind that this list does include some references to societies from other realities.

Comment: Don't forget the Ramurans. I added an edit suggestion.

Comment: Several civilizations that are able to produce cloaking technology would occasionally trade, sell, or lose (to theft) a cloaking device or three. I'm not sure all of the civilizations here are able to produce their own cloaks, as several of them only exhibit one or two examples that could have been obtained elsewhere.

Answer (score 9):

The Aldeans are a race of people who cloak their entire planet in [*When The Bough Breaks*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/When_The_Bough_Breaks_(episode)).

[Suliban](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Suliban) also have cloaking technology.

Quark managed to acquire a damaged cloaking device on the black market. He ultimately gave it to some Cardassians in [*Profit and Loss*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Profit_and_Loss_(episode)).

In [*Blaze of Glory*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Blaze_of_Glory_(episode)), the Klingon empire supplied cloaking devices to the Maquis for use against Cardassia.